# Extract values from JSON file

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have this JSON file:

```
{
  "entityId": "proc_1234",
  "displayName": "oracle12",
  "firstSeenTms": 1639034760000,
  "lastSeenTms": 1650386100000,
  "properties": {
    "detectedName": "oracle.sysman.gcagent.tmmain.TMMain",
    "bitness": "64",
    "jvmVendor": "IBM",
    "metadata": [
      {
        "key": "COMMAND_LINE_ARGS",
        "value": "/usr/local/oracle/oem/agent12c/agent_13.3.0.0.0"
      },
      {
        "key": "EXE_NAME",
        "value": "java"
      },
      {
        "key": "EXE_PATH",
        "value": "/usr/local/oracle/oem/agent*c/agent_*/oracle_common/jdk/bin/java"
      },
      {
        "key": "JAVA_MAIN_CLASS",
        "value": "oracle.sysman.gcagent.tmmain.TMMain"
      },
      {
        "key": "EXE_PATH",
        "value": "/usr/local/oracle/oem/agent12c/agent_13.3.0.0.0/oracle_common/jdk/bin/java"
      }
    ]
   }
}
```

I need to extract entityId, detectedName, EXE_NAME, EXE_PATH from the json file.

output should be like this:

```
entityId    detectedName                           EXE_NAME    EXE_PATH
proc_1234   oracle.sysman.gcagent.tmmain.TMMain     java       /usr/local/oracle/oem/agent*c/agent_*/oracle_common/jdk/bin/java
```

I have tried this:

```
Procdf = (pd.json_normalize(resp2, record_path=['properties', 'metadata'], meta=['entityId']).drop_duplicates(subset=['key']) .query("key in ['EXE_NAME','EXE_PATH']").pivot('entityId', 'key', 'value', 'detectedName').reset_index())
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: pivot() takes from 1 to 4 positional arguments but 5 were given
```

Comment: Why did you pass 5 arguments to pivot and not between 1 and 4?

Comment: So, what prevents you from converting JSON to `dict` using `json` from stdlib and indexing the heck out of it?

Comment: @KlasŠ. I would appreciate your thoughts, new to python.

Comment: @mkrieger1, I need to pick another field called detectedName from the json file

Comment: You probably are supposed to pass a list of field names as one argument, rather than as individual arguments. I would check what the documentation for the pivot function says about this.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear to me what exactly the purpose of pivot is. But you are trying to pivot detectedName, that's not in your dataframe. Below might be what you need.

```
import pandas as pd
det_name = list(resp2.get('properties','detectedName').values())[0]
dataframe = pd.json_normalize(resp2, record_path=['properties', 'metadata'], meta=['entityId']).drop_duplicates(subset=['key']).query("key in ['EXE_NAME','EXE_PATH']").assign(detectedName=det_name).T
print(type(dataframe))
```

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

[image: result]

Comment: the result need to be a data frame. I'm getting something like this:    0  \
key                                          EXE_NAME   
value                                   ndschedag.exe   
entityId      PROCESS_GROUP_INSTANCE-05015C 
detectedName                           Schedule Agent

Comment: how can I convert this to a data frame?

Comment: its a dateframe, so ?